# very simple python 3 try except ValueError not tripping

Tags: python, python-3.x, try-catch

trying to get my try except block to work.

```
import sys

def main():
    try:
        test = int("hello")
    except ValueError:
        print("test")
        raise

main()
```

output is

```
C:\Python33>python.exe test.py
test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 10, in <module>
    main()
  File "test.py", line 5, in main
    test = int("hello")
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello'

C:\Python33>
```

would like the except to trip

Comment: This is expected as you are raising the exception using raise

Comment: You should read the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-raise-statement) for `raise`.  The first sentence states: `If no expressions are present, raise re-raises the last exception that was active in the current scope.`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are reraising the exception. It's working as designed.

The `test` is printed right at the top there before the traceback, but you used `raise` so the exception still is causing a traceback:

```
>>> def main():
...     try:
...         test = int("hello")
...     except ValueError:
...         print("test")
...         raise
... 
>>> main()
test
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in main
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'hello'
```

Remove the `raise` and just the `test` print remains:

```
>>> def main():
...     try:
...         test = int("hello")
...     except ValueError:
...         print("test")
... 
>>> main()
test
```